# AutoFixture type customization not invoked

Tags: autofixture

### Given

This is my class structure being tested.

```
public class Company
{
    public List<Department> Departments { get; set; }
}

public class Department
{
    public List<Employee> Employees { get; set; }
}

public class Employee
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public DateTime HireDate { get; set; }
}
```

And I want to have an customized object of `Employee` added to `Department.Employees` when AutoFixture is told to `Create<Company>()`.

I would think this should be written thus:

```
_fixture.Customize<Department>(
            c => c.Do(d => d.Employees
                            .Add(_fixture.Build<Employee>()
                                         .With(e => e.Name, "simple name")
                                         .Create())));

_fixtrue.Create<Company>();
```

### However

When I run the test, the `Company.Departments` property is populated with 3 objects, and each of those three objects has a `Department.Employees` list populated with 3 objects (expected 4 or 1) and none of the `Employee` objects have the name specified. **Why?**

### Possibly relevant

I am also using the `AutoNSubstituteCustomization` and a homegrown implementation of `ISpecimenBuilder` for an unrelated type on the fixture.

That `ISpecimenBuilder` is:

```
    public class PropertyTypeOmission 
    {
        public SelectionContext<TDeclaringType> For<TDeclaringType>()
        {
            return new SelectionContext<TDeclaringType>();
        }

        public class SelectionContext<TDeclaringType> 
        {
            public OmitMemberTypeByType Omitting<TPropertyType>()
            {
                return new OmitMemberTypeByType(typeof(TDeclaringType), typeof(TPropertyType));
            }

            public OmitMemberTypeByType Omitting<TMemberType>(Expression<Func<TDeclaringType, TMemberType>> select)
            {
                var memberExp = GetMemberExpression(select);
                var property = GetPropertyInfo(memberExp);
                if (property != null)
                {
                    return new OmitMemberTypeByType(typeof(TDeclaringType), property.PropertyType);
                }

                var field = GetFieldInfo(memberExp);
                if (field != null)
                {
                    return new OmitMemberTypeByType(typeof(TDeclaringType), field.FieldType);
                }

                throw new ArgumentException("Only field or property selectors allowed");
            }


            private static PropertyInfo GetPropertyInfo(MemberExpression memberExp)
            {
                if (!(memberExp.Member is PropertyInfo property))
                {
                    return null;
                }

                return property;
            }

            private static MemberExpression GetMemberExpression<TMemberType>(Expression<Func<TDeclaringType, TMemberType>> select)
            {
                if (!(select.Body is MemberExpression memberExp))
                {
                    throw new ArgumentException("only member expressions are allowed");
                }

                return memberExp;
            }

            private static FieldInfo GetFieldInfo(MemberExpression memberExp)
            {
                if (!(memberExp.Member is FieldInfo field))
                {
                    return null;
                }

                return field;
            }
        }
    }

    public class OmitMemberTypeByType : ISpecimenBuilder
    {
        private Type _declaringType;
        private Type _memberType;

        public OmitMemberTypeByType(Type declaringType, Type memberType)
        {
            _declaringType = declaringType;
            _memberType = memberType;
        }

        public object Create(object request, ISpecimenContext context)
        {
            if ((!(request is PropertyInfo propertyInfo)
                || propertyInfo.DeclaringType != _declaringType
                || propertyInfo.PropertyType != _memberType) 
                && 
                (!(request is FieldInfo fieldInfo)
                || fieldInfo.DeclaringType != _declaringType
                || fieldInfo.FieldType != _memberType))
            {
                return new NoSpecimen();
            }

            return new OmitSpecimen();
        }
    }
```

used as

```
_fixture.Customizations.Add(new PropertyTypeOmission().For<State>().Omitting(s => s.SqMiles));
```

Answer (score 0):

The customization example you gave threw an exception for me.
It did that because the Employees property was not initialized, and then one of cource can't .Add() anything to it.

This worked for me:

```cs
List<Employee> EmployeesFactory((List<Employee> employees, Employee employee) input)
{
    input.employee.Name = "simple name";
    input.employees.Add(input.employee);
    return input.employees;
}

_fixture
    .Customize<Department>(c =>
        c.With<List<Employee>, (List<Employee>, Employee)>(
            x => x.Employees,
            EmployeesFactory));
```

Comment: You are using `.CreateMany(4)` with every employee having `.Name` equal `Simple Name`. This is not what I'm asking for. I want to have AutoFixture populate the `Department.Employees` auto property with anonymous objects and then I want to add `1` Employee with `Simple Name`.

Comment: It seems as though autofixture will not create the Employees, if the property is 'touched' in the customizer. I don't know how to change that behaviour. Therefore I edited my answer, so the customization generates the data you ask for. @JoshGust

Comment: I don't have a problem finding a work around. The [documentation](https://blog.ploeh.dk/2009/09/22/CustomizingAType'sBuilderWithAutoFixture/) seems to say that I should be able to write my customization as in my question and expect `4 or 1` (as I haven't seen this work i can't say if I should expect my custom obj to be added to or replace the first 3 created).

Comment: The reason why it works in Mark Seemans example, is found in [the post preceding](https://blog.ploeh.dk/2009/08/25/DoRedux/) the one you linked to. It shows that the `AvailableItems` property's backingfield on the `MainViewModel` isn't initialized by AutoFixture, but by the `MainViewModel`s constructor. (`this.availableItems = new List<MyClass>();`) @JoshGust

Comment: That makes more sense then. Having a setter on the property allows AF to populate it. **Is there any documentation that illustrates this behavior will overwrite values assigned in a customization like mine?** I understand that using `.Without(d => d.Employees)` prior to `.Do(...)` would stop the builder from assigning via the setter after I've invoked `.Add()` on the list. So, `f.Customize<D>(c=>c.Without(d=>d.Es).Do(d=>{d.Es.Add(f.CreateMany<E>(3)); d.Es.Add(f.Build<E>().With(e=>e.Name, "simple").Create());}));` should work, right?

Comment: The [Internal Architure page](https://github.com/AutoFixture/AutoFixture/wiki/Internal-Architecture) illustrates that customizations comes first. But AF doesn't overwrite customized properties. If a property has a value, AF leaves it alone. The purpose of `.Without` is when you want the engine parts to ignore it, even though it is null/has no value , and it is not necessary to use it when you want to assign the property a value. @JoshGust

Comment: This still doesn't explain my problem then. If I initialize the lists in the ctor of the containing class (so that `.Do( ...Add())` doesn't throw a null reference exception) my customization works fine at first as I'm debugging, but then the property setters are hit and my added item is replaced with 3 anonymous employee objects that, none of which have my desired value.

Comment: I just tested, and you're right, I was a bit to fast. If you initialize it in the class, and have a public setter, you need the `.Without` in order to not get it overwritten, if you only use `.Do()` in the customization. If you use `.With(...)`, as pr my answer, it doesn't get overwritten, and then it's not necessary. @JoshGust